# What does lexing error mean in ninja?

Tags: makefile, ninja

I am using ninja to build a program for the first time. I run the command 'ninja -f hello.c' from the cmd but get the error "ninja: error: hello.c:1: lexing error". Why is this occuring? Here is my build.ninja file:

```
# build.ninja
cc     = clang
cflags = -Weverything

rule compile
command = $cc $cflags -c $in -o $out

rule link
command = $cc $in -o $out

build hello.o: compile hello.c
build hello: link hello.o

default hello
```

Here is Hello.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello World");

}
```

Comment: `main()` -> `int main()`

Comment: That did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are trying to take a `.c` file where you would need a `build.ninja` as an input for your build (so `ninja` is complaining about the syntax of your build description file).

See the `-f` option description:

```
usage: ninja [options] [targets...]
...
  -f FILE  specify input build file [default=build.ninja]
```

So don't specify `-f` if you want to select a target to be build.

**Reference**

- [The Ninja build system](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html)